# Selecting data from 3 tables in database in Codeigniter

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

I want to collect values from 3 tables in a database. I have used following code;

```
public function view_event( $where=array())
 {

     $this->db->select('client.name, client.contact,event.eid, event.hall, event.event_date, 
     event.time, event.guests, payment.Paid'); 
     $this->db->where($where);
     $this->db->from('client', 'event');
     $this->db->join('event', 'event.client_id = client.id');
     $this->db->join('payment', 'payment.event_id = event.eid');
     $result = $this->db->get();
     return $result->result();

 }
```

But this code gives following error;
Error Number: 1054

> Unknown column 'payment.Paid' in 'field list'

Comment: Please check if there is a column with name 'Paid' in the payment table.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: yes i fixed it, but i am getting redundant data now

Comment: I have removed the conflicting tags for now. Please retag the RDBMS you are using, and *only* the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: using phpmyadmin

Comment: the unknown col is fixed its amount instead of Paid.

Comment: But now this code is giving redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 public function view_event( $where=array())
 {
  $this->db->select('client.name, 
  client.contact,event.eid,event.hall,event.event_date, event.time, 
  event.guests, 
  payment.Paid')
        ->from('client')
        ->join('event', 'event.client_id = client.id', 'LEFT')
        ->join('payment', 'payment.event_id = event.eid', 'LEFT')
  return $this->db->get()->result();
 }
```